# Установка OpenStack packstack. Проблема с gateway

Tags: linux, centos

Для теста OpenStack Heat решил быстро развернуть его с помощью packstack. Однако возникло несколько проблем (если кому вдруг пригодится, в дополнение к инструкции https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/ надо добавить yum install python-setuptools, yum install python-pip). Однако решение проблемы сборки так и не нашел. На этапе команды sudo packstack-allinone выдает Local ip address discovery failed. Please set a default gateway for your system. Однако добавление GATEWAY в /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 проблему не решило. Скрин вывода ifconfig и ifcfg-enp0s3 прилагаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]